# How to use your custom c# property?

Tags: c#, controls

This sets a true/false property to design mode:

```
private bool m_myProp;

[Description("Set meatspin"),Category("Values"),DefaultValue(0),Browsable(true)]
public bool Testprop
{   
    get 
    {
        return m_myProp;
    }
    set
    {
        m_myProp = value;
        this.AutoSize = value; // test if it also changes a standard property
    }   
}
```

Now I want it to work like this: When the user sets the property to `true` a certain action will be taken.

How do I do that with a custom control and custom property?

How can I let the custom property behave like the basic property `enabled = true`?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Can't you just to `if(value == true) { //do something }` in the `set` block?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you want to do? just use:

```
if(m_myProp) {
```

anywhere in the class.. if in the set block, after you've set it to value of course.

or

```
if(obj.Testprop) {
```

anywhere outside it..  Where obj is an instance of that class that has the Testprop property.

Comment: I figures it out just before you put the same answer it works fine now thanx for the answer though. I will go on testing with it.

Comment: @Michael, if this is the correct answer, please accept it by clicking the check mark. It's considered SO courtesy.